# How can I determine the cycle lengths in a directed graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a directed graph:

```
a = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}; 
AdjacencyGraph[a]
```

I want to determine the cycle lengths in the directed graph.  In the example above I would want Mathematica to return {3,4} because there is a cycle of length 3 and a cycle of length 4 in the directed graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}};
g = AdjacencyGraph[a];

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

> {3, 4}

Comment: OK Thanks,  but...    I need to include cycles of length 2.  For example: a = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}; Map[Length, FindCycle[AdjacencyGraph[a], Infinity, All]]    returns {}.   Is there a way to convert the adjacency matrix into a list of edges and then use FindCycle?

Comment: @geoffrey I think you want to add the option `DirectedEdges -> True`, i.e., `AdjacencyGraph[a, DirectedEdges -> True]`.  Then it should work.